# Syntax error in the pygame collision detection function python3

Tags: python, function, pygame, collision-detection, game-physics

so I try to program a 2d game platform like space invaders, but the problem is in the collision, when I try to define the collision, which I use in her  characteristics, the characteristics of the classes (enemy coordinates and the bullet coordinates), the code won't start. And this is the result : `

```
    def isc (eneemy.x, eneemy.y, Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y ):
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is the code if you need it :

```
    ############# LIBRARIES ####################
import pygame, sys, random
import math
from pygame.constants import SYSTEM_CURSOR_WAITARROW 
from pygame import mixer


pygame.init()

############ WINDOW OPTIONS ################
Swidth = 800 
Sheight =600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Swidth, Sheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader By Mal4D")
icon = pygame.image.load('places/favicon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


############# COLORS #######################
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255 , 255 , 0)

###########  VARIANTS ######################
isJumping= False
LevelJump = 0.25
rocket = pygame.image.load("rocket/rocket.png")
space = pygame.image.load("places/bg.png")
bullet = pygame.image.load("rocket/bullet.png")
Sound =  pygame.mixer.music.load("Sounds/laser.mp3")
Bgsound= pygame.mixer.music.load("Sounds/bg.mp3")
enemy = pygame.image.load("Enemy/enemy.png")
ax=random.randint(0,700)
by=random.randint(20,120)
Bgsound1 = mixer.Sound("Sounds/bg.mp3")
BullletSound = mixer.Sound("Sounds/laser.mp3")


############## Class Players ##########################
class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.step=10
        self.speed=10
        self.isJumping= False
        

    def drawplayer (self,screen):
        screen.blit(rocket, (rockeet.x, rockeet.y))

    def drawscreen (self,screen):
        screen.blit(space, (0,0))
    

rockeet = Player(350,500,50,50)


########### Bullet #####################
class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, x, y , y_change, x_change, state):
        self.x=x
        self.y= y
        self.y_change=y_change
        self.x_change= x_change
        self.state= state


    def fire(x,y):
        Bulllet.state = "fire"
        screen.blit(bullet,(x+16, y+10))


Bulllet=Bullet(350,500,20,0,"ready")

**def isCollision (ax1, by1, cx, dy):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(ax1 - cx, 2) + (math.pow(by1- dy, 2)))

    if distance <27:
        return True
    else:
        return False**

    
################## Enemy ########################
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, x ,y, stepx,stepy):
        self.x = x
        self.y=y
        self.stepx=stepx
        self.stepy=stepy


    def drawenemy(screen):
        screen.blit(enemy,(ax,by))


eneemy = Enemy(random.randint(0,700),random.randint(20,120),3,35)


################# Clussion#########################
score = 0


def isc (eneemy.x, eneemy.y, Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y ):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(eneemy.x - Bulllet.x, 2) + (math.pow(eneemy.y- Bulllet.y, 2)))

    if distance <27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


################### Game Loop #####################################
#Bgsound1.play(180)




while 1:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rockeet.drawscreen(screen)
    Enemy.drawenemy(screen)



    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if Bulllet.state == "ready":
            BullletSound.play()

            Bulllet.x=rockeet.x
            Bulllet.y=rockeet.y
            Bullet.fire(Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y)



    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and rockeet.x - rockeet.step >= 0:
        rockeet.x =rockeet.x-rockeet.step
    
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and rockeet.x + rockeet.width +rockeet.step <= Swidth :
        rockeet.x =rockeet.x+rockeet.step

    if Bulllet.y <= 0:
        Bulllet.y= 500
        Bulllet.state = "ready"


    if Bulllet.state == "fire":
        Bullet.fire(Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y)
        Bulllet.y -= Bulllet.y_change



########### Enemy Mouvement #########################################
    collision = isCollision( eneemy.x, eneemy.y, Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y)

    ax+= eneemy.stepx
    if ax<= 0:
        eneemy.stepx=3
        by+= eneemy.stepy

    elif ax >= 750:
        eneemy.stepx=-3
        by+= eneemy.stepy

    if collision:
        Bulllet.y= 500
        Bulllet.state="ready"
        eneemy.x= random.randint(0,700)
        eneemy.y=random.randint(20,)

################## Collision ######################








################## OUTRO #######################################
    rockeet.drawplayer(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

the result:

```
def isCollision (eneemy.x, eneemy.y, Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y ):
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal parameters  of a function cannot be structure elements like `eneemy.x`. Either Change the names of the parameters:

```py
def isc (enemy_x, enemy_y, bullet_x, bullet_y):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemy_x - bullet_x, 2) + (math.pow(enemy_y- bullet_y, 2)))

    if distance <27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or pass the objects to the function:

```py
def isc (enemy, bullet):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemy.x - bullet.x, 2) + (math.pow(enemy.y- bullet.y, 2)))

    if distance <27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

<s>`collision = isCollision( eneemy.x, eneemy.y, Bulllet.x, Bulllet.y)`</s>

```py
collision = isCollision(eneemy, Bulllet)
```

---

Note, that you can use `math.hypot` instead of `math.sqrt` and `math.pow`:

<s>`distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemy_x - bullet_x, 2) + (math.pow(enemy_y- bullet_y, 2)))`</s>

```py
distance = math.hypot(enemy_x - bullet_x, enemy_y - bullet_y)
```